# How to not list "." and ".." in curl command : " curl -l ftp: "

Tags: bash, shell, curl, ftp

Command : `curl -l ftp://test:test@test/test/`

Mission : Not list "`.`" and "`..`"

Output :

```
.
..
test.txt
test_2.txt
```

Desired output :

```
test.txt
test_2.txt
```

Comment: Either make changes to your ftp server side, or just grep -v these lines from the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed. I suggest to append this to your command to delete rows containing only one or two dots:

```
| sed -r '/^\.{1,2}$/d'
```

And add to curl option `-s` (silent) to suppress its statistics output.

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Your code works, but this time, `curl` adds `% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current` to the top of the list. It is actually more, there are 3 lines.  This is the way I tested your code :  `test="ftp://test:test@test/test/"` ... `curl -l $test |  sed -r '/^\.{1,2}$/d'`

Comment: I suggest to add option `-s` (silent) to curl.

Comment: Adding the "`-s`" flag worked. The comment under the answer in regards to the `s` flag should be seen as part of the answer. I am selecting this answer as the "chosen answer".